# Put Border-radius in a clip path

Tags: html, css, transform, clip-path

[image]

Is there a way to put a border-radius in a clip path?

Here is my code;

clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 96% 100%, 5% 100%);
border-radius: 93px 66px 80px 80px;

Comment: Please explain some more what you are trying to do - 'rotate an image to the front' doesn't make sense to me. Also please include the code you have tried and describe what isn't working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Add your html code. Or make an snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [SVG clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to define an area to be clipped in another SVG and set its width and height to zero so it doesn't take any space in the viewport. We use the [defs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs) element to store the clip path so we can use it in another SVG.

SVGs can include images via the [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) element and then use the `clip-path` attribute to apply the clipping SVG. You can then get creative using a path editor like [svg path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) and make any shape you like.

Example below

```css
#image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-0.110253 0 50.22 50" id='clipsvg' width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <path d="M 10 0 L 40 0 C 45 0 51 5 50 10 L 45 40 C 45 45 40 50 35 50 L 15 50 C 10 50 6 45 5 40 L 0 10 C -1 5 5 0 10 0" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg id='image' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-0.110253 0 50.22 50">
  <image width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#mask)" href="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
</svg>
```

You can also use `mask-image` to achieve the same thing. You do need to encode your svg. [URL encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) is good for this

```css
img {
  mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-1 0 51 50'%3E%3Cpath d='M 10 0 L 40 0 C 45 0 51 5 50 10 L 45 40 C 45 45 40 50 35 50 L 15 50 C 10 50 6 45 5 40 L 0 10 C -1 5 5 0 10 0'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  center center;
  -webkit-mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-1 0 51 50'%3E%3Cpath d='M 10 0 L 40 0 C 45 0 51 5 50 10 L 45 40 C 45 45 40 50 35 50 L 15 50 C 10 50 6 45 5 40 L 0 10 C -1 5 5 0 10 0'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  center center;
  mask-size: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placekitten.com/200/200'>
```